# Highchart manage state manually

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way in highchart to remove the default state mecanism ?

it seems like the auto changing hover state is resetting my manually set state.

what I'm trying to achieve is selecting the series when user click on it.

I've added the select state like this :

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
               states: {
                     select: {

                            lineWidth: 2
                     }
               },
```

and I'm setting this state manually with :

```
this.setState(this.state === 'select' ? '' : 'select');
```

the lineWidth change is working but, when I move the mouse around it resets the lineWidth back ( I guess its because some hover event being fired but I'm not sure about it.)

I already tried to disable the hover state, without any success :

```
states: {
    hover: {
        enabled: false
    },
    select: {
            lineWidth: 3
```

the exact problem can be see on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9d9H/5/) when you click on series lines, its selected then move around it deselects...  I can't uderstand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the state manually at all times, then you can turn off the "Normal"/Reset state by adding the following snippet to your code before you instantiate any graphs. All it does is cancel the setState operation if no parameters were passed (aka the Highcharts source code is trying to revert the series to normal).

```
Highcharts.Series.prototype.setState = (function (func) {
        return function () {
            if (arguments.length>0){
                func.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };
    } (Highcharts.Series.prototype.setState));
```

Let me know if that is what you're looking for! Here's the modified JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G9d9H/8/

EDIT: Just a little but of further explanation, what the Highcharts source code is actually doing, is that if you `mouseOver` a series, it automatically reverts all other series to default style. As this is most likely the #1 use case of the state functionality, I'm assuming that's why they coded it that way.